# Переадресация методом POST

Tags: post, php, ссылки, форма

Как сделать переадресацию на другую страницу с анкором, но методом `POST`? Если писать

```
http://myste.org/index.php?login=vasya&pass=1234...
```

то его видно в строке браузера. Можно сделать формой, но там, насколько я знаю, нужно сотворить кнопку `submit`. Нет ли способа проще?

Comment: C учетом твоей ссылки это уже GET а не POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax, Curl - но это без переадресации.
Есть также вариант сделать форму со скрытыми полями, сабмит "Перейти" и автоматическую отправку формы (для тех, у кого не отключен js).
Больше способов не знаю. Флеш, Java?..

Answer (score 1):

Никак.
[Hypertext Transfer Protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3)

Comment: Ссылка не открывается.